# Using the where command in List to iterate through its content

Tags: dart

I am playing around with Dart and came up with the following code

```
List<String> lst = new List<String>();

  main()
{
  lst.add("hello");
  lst.where((String str) {
    if(str=="hello"){
      print("Found");
    }
  });
}
```

While debugging I noticed its not going into the where statement and printing "Found" . Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  var filteredList = lst.where((String str) {
    if(str=="hello"){
      print("Found");
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
  print(filteredList);
```

`where()`

- should return `true` or `false` to indicate whether the item fulfills the condition
- creates and returns a new iterable, it does not modify the original collection
- is lazy, which means it is not executed before the result is used. `toList()` is one of the operations that require the result to materialize and to execute the where condition on every item (many collection methods are lazy).

Comment: Perhaps worth a note because of bullet one. The shorthand function syntax `() => expression` implicitly returns the result of `expression`, but if you use a function body like `() { expressions and statements }` you need to `return` explicitly.